# DateTime.Parse: exception when changing culture

Tags: c#, .net

I am parsing a string to convert it into a DateTime.  I am getting in some cases an error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I am getting this error only if I run the application from a computer located in a different country than US.  What I see in the string is `09/20/2010 14:11` and in this case I get an exception. If I have a value like: `10/05/2010 12:54` I don't get an exception.  I suppose it is the fact that the day is 20 and this computer is in Europe, so it thinks that 20 is the month. The problem is I force it to be en-US:

```
CompletedDttm = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Because I am getting the exception I suppose sure this is the correct approach.

Any idea how to parse a string in a way that works no matter what culture I am running on the machine?

Comment: If you know that the format will always be like that, you could use DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); In terms of date and time format, InvariantCulture is roughly an equivalent of en-US. BTW, if you parse it like this, .Net will not be able to determine the time zone and it will actually treat your DateTime as "unspecified local" which could lead to errors. If you know that the source is in UTC use this: DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use "HH:mm" instead of "hh:mm" - "HH" is for 24-hour clock; "hh" is for a 12-hour clock. So 14 isn't a valid value for "hh".

I'd expect to see the same problem even on a US machine though... maybe you happened to only get pre-1pm times on your US machines due to time zone differences?